# discord.js v12 command args

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get some info from the message and show it in an embed. But when I run this code I get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzERN.png)

Here is my code:

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
  async function getinfo() {
    let lol1 = args[1]
    let lol2 = args.slice(2).join(' ')

    const whois = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("test1:")
      .addField("test2", ` ${lol1} / ${lol2}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setTimestamp()

    message.channel.send(whois)
  }
  getinfo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How are arguments defined?

The definition of arguments in discord.js is any user input **after** the command itself. So, if we look at the basic template of how arguments look like:

```
[Prefix][Command] [args]
```

Meaning that 'args' already splits off the prefix and the command already, living us with the `args` variable, who is basically an array of the arguments provided:

```
const args = ['first argument', 'second argument', 'third argument', ...];
```

From this logic, when you're inserting '123' and '123' as your arguments, we're getting the following array:

```
const args = ['123', '123'];
```

And since we're always starting at `0` when getting array values, the first '123' would be referred to as `args[0]` while the second '123' would be referred to as `args[1]`.

#### Final Code

```
run: async (client, message, args) => {

        async function getinfo() {
        let lol1 = args[0];
        let lol2 = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    
    
        const whothefuq = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle("test1:")
              .addField("test2", ` ${lol1} / ${lol2}`)
              .setColor("RANDOM")
              .setTimestamp()
          message.channel.send(whothefuq)
        
        }
    
        getinfo();
    }
```